# Running asm procedure in cpp file

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-studio-2013, masm, irvine32

I am trying to run procedure from asm file in cpp file but i get such errors:

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _calka referenced in function _main   D:\Addem\main.obj   Project
Error   2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   D:\Addem\Debug\Project.exe  1   1   Project
```

Here is my main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

extern "C" void calka();

int main()
{
    calka();

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

And my calka.asm

```
; The calka Subroutine    (calka.asm)
public _calka                  

INCLUDELIB kernel32.lib
INCLUDELIB user32.lib
INCLUDELIB Irvine32.lib
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
INCLUDE macros.inc



.data
BUFFER_SIZE = 50
buffer BYTE BUFFER_SIZE DUP(?)
filename    BYTE 80 DUP(0)
fileHandle  HANDLE ?
Rozmiar dw ?
Znak db ?
Suma dw ?
Minus db 0
wynik dw ?
temp dd ?

.code
_calka proc near

; Let user input a filename.
    mWrite "Podaj nazwe pliku (z rozszerzeniem): "
    mov edx,OFFSET filename
    mov ecx,SIZEOF filename
    call    ReadString

; Open the file for input.
    mov edx,OFFSET filename
    call    OpenInputFile
    mov fileHandle,eax

; Check for errors.
    cmp eax,INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE        ; error opening file?
    jne file_ok                 ; no: skip
    mWrite <"Cannot open file",0dh,0ah>
    jmp quit                        ; and quit
file_ok:

; Read the file into a buffer.
    mov edx,OFFSET buffer
    mov ecx,BUFFER_SIZE
    call    ReadFromFile
    jnc check_buffer_size           ; error reading?
    mWrite "Error reading file. "       ; yes: show error message
    call    WriteWindowsMsg
    jmp close_file

check_buffer_size:
    cmp eax,BUFFER_SIZE         ; buffer large enough?
    jb  buf_size_ok             ; yes
    mWrite <"Error: Buffer too small for the file",0dh,0ah>
    jmp quit                        ; and quit

buf_size_ok:    
    mov buffer[eax],0       ; insert null terminator
    ;mWrite "File size: "
    ;call   WriteDec            ; display file size
    ;call   Crlf

; Display the buffer.


; Pytanie o wielkosc przedzialu

    mWrite "Podaj wielkosc przedzialu h na osi x: "
    mov edx,OFFSET Rozmiar
    mov ecx,SIZEOF Rozmiar
    call    ReadDec

    mov Rozmiar, ax


    ;mWrite <"Buffer:",0dh,0ah,0dh,0ah>
    ;mov    edx,OFFSET buffer   ; display the buffer
    ;call   WriteString
    ;call   Crlf

    mov ecx, 15
    mov ebx, OFFSET buffer

mov si, 0
        jmp odczyt1
odczyt:
        mov ebx, temp
        inc ebx

odczyt1:
        mov cl, byte ptr [ebx]
        mov Znak, cl

        mov temp, ebx

        cmp Znak, '$' ;koniec pliku
        je koniec
        cmp Znak, 3bh ;srednik - nastepna liczba
        je nastepna
        cmp Znak, 20h ;spacja - ponowne wczytanie
        je odczyt
        cmp Znak, '-'
        je Zmien_znak


        mov al, Znak
        sub al, 30h
        mov bl, al
        mov bh, 0
        mov ax, 10
        mul si
        add ax, bx
        mov si, ax
        jmp odczyt

Zmien_znak:
        mov Minus, 1
        jmp odczyt

nastepna:
        cmp Minus, 0
        je dodaj
        jne odejm
dodaj:
        add Suma, si
        mov si, 0
        jmp odczyt
odejm:
        sub Suma, si
        mov Minus, 0
        mov si, 0
        jmp odczyt

koniec:
        cmp Minus, 0
        je dod
        jne minu
dod:
        add Suma, si
        mov si, 0
        jmp kon
minu:
        sub Suma, si
        mov Minus, 0
        mov si, 0
kon:
        mov ax, Suma
        mul Rozmiar

    mWrite "Wynik calkowania: "
    cmp ax,0
    ;mov ebx, eax
    jg plus
    mWrite "-"
    mov bx, 0
    sub bx, ax
    mov ax, bx

plus:
    call WriteDec


close_file:
    mov eax,fileHandle
    call    CloseFile

    ; Zeby aplikacja sie nie zamknela, heheszki :D
    mov edx,OFFSET Rozmiar
    mov ecx,SIZEOF Rozmiar
    call    ReadString

quit:
    exit
_calka ENDP

END
```

I have tried everything what I can focus on - adding obj files to linker and so on. I only want to type the name of file, read date from it and calculate it. Calka.asm works well unless I try to get it work in my cpp file.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `adding obj files to linker` - so, have you added `calka.obj`, and does it get created by assembling first? Does VS maybe show you the command it is running, and if so, does that include `calka.obj`?

Comment: I have clear my solution, and after that I compile calka.asm with right click in Solution Explorer. After that I have added calka.obj with option "Add Existing item" - what I get after building project is: `Debug\calka.obj : warning LNK4042: object specified more than once; extras ignored` Something more to do?

Comment: I'm not sure if "Add Existing Item" is the way to add an object file, isn't there a specific tab in the project property somewhere in the linker/compiler options? Maybe it's the same, just a guess.

Comment: How to do it correctly? I have tried plenty of ways but nothing get it to work :).

Comment: According to this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946513/how-to-include-obj-files-into-the-project) there is no diiference in including method...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Irvine32.inc` includes `SmallWin.inc` and that sets `.MODEL flat, stdcall`. So, every procedure will be decorated by default as if the calling convention were [STDCALL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/zxk0tw93.aspx). `_calka` becomes `_calka@0`. For the [CDECL calling convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/zkwh89ks.aspx) needed for `main.cpp` you have to override the default calling convention for the procedure with `PROC C`. Now the underscore will be added automatically. TLDR: `calka proc C`.

The best is, you create a new project. I'll describe the procedure for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 RC on Windows 10. The procedure is quite similar for other VS versions.

1) Start Visual Studio 2015 RC and choose `FILE - New - Project`.

[image: Screenshot]

2) In the next window choose `Win 32 Console Application`.

[image: Screenshot]

3) You get a confirmation. Click on `Next >`.

[image: Screenshot]

4) In the next window choose
   [X] Console application
   [X] Empty project
   Click on `Finish`.

[image: Screenshot]

5) Make sure, that the project is highlighted in the Solution Explorer and choose `PROJECT - Build Customizations...`.

[image: Screenshot]

6) In the next window tick `masm(.targets,.props)` and click on `OK`.

[image: Screenshot]

7) Create main.cpp: `PROJECT - Add New Item`.

[image: Screenshot]

8) In the next window choose `C++File(.cpp)`, give it a name and click on `Add`.

[image: Screenshot]

9) Create calka.asm: `PROJECT - Add New Item`. In the next window choose `C++File(.cpp)` and - IMPORTANT! - give it a name with `.asm` extension. Click on `Add`.

[image: Screenshot]

10) Now check if the `.asm` file has the right properties. In the Solution Explorer right-click on the file and choose `Properties`.

[image: Screenshot]

11) In the Property Page you should see
   Excluded From Build    (empty) or No
   Item Build             Microsoft Macro Assembler
   Click on `OK`.

[image: Screenshot]

12) Now you can fill the files with content.

[image: Screenshot]

You don't need `system("Pause")` since <kbd>CTRL-F5</kbd> builds, runs and pauses the application.

In the `.asm` file delete

```
INCLUDELIB kernel32.lib
INCLUDELIB user32.lib
```

and let Visual Studio them automatically include. Add to

```
INCLUDELIB Irvine32.lib
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
INCLUDE macros.inc
```

the full path to the files. That's better than to change the settings of VS.

Change

```
_calka proc near
...
_calka ENDP
```

to

```
calka PROC C
...
calka ENDP
```

13) Build and run with <kbd>CTRL-F5</kbd>.

[image: Screenshot]

The application will be opened in a new window.