# Visual Studio 2013 Does Not add MASM build dependency

Tags: visual-studio, masm

I'm trying to add MASM to my project in visual studio. for this I have found that I must add this from buid dependencies menu. but the problem is , ticking the MASM option DOES'NT add MASM to my project. I've noticed that there must be a name under Name category in the below picture, but there is no name in there (?) and maby that's why it is not working. Any help on how can I fix this or how
can I add MASM to my project would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Continue with par. 7) [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037176/running-asm-procedure-in-cpp-file/31056748#31056748) ;-)

Comment: Thnx for your reply but the problem is in step 11, my Visual Studio does not have a Microsoft Micro Assembler Item Type ?!