# Symbols already defined error when compiling assembly output from Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, assembly, linker, masm32

Currently using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.4.4 and compiling a C project.

I want to be able to output assembly from VS, make modifications to the assembly, and then compile the modified assembly into an executable file. Below I talk about my attempts following instructions from a previous SO question, but if there is an alternative (even not using VS) I would appreciate those suggestions.

As a test, I have been using a simple "hello world" program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv) {
    printf("Hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried compiling this program following the instructions given by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815636/compile-assembly-output-generated-by-vc/21204272#21204272) but I get the following errors:

> LNK2005   ___local_stdio_printf_options already defined in helloworld.obj
>
> LNK1169   one or more multiply defined symbols found

It looks like VS is actually compiling the assembly to object files, but the linker says that the "___local_stdio_printf_options" symbol is already defined at link-time. When I look back at the assembly code output from VS, this seems to be true:

```
___local_stdio_printf_options PROC          ; COMDAT
; File C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_stdio_config.h
; Line 86
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp
; Line 88
    mov eax, OFFSET ?_OptionsStorage@?1??__local_stdio_printf_options@@9@9 ; `__local_stdio_printf_options'::`2'::_OptionsStorage
; Line 89
    pop ebp
    ret 0
___local_stdio_printf_options ENDP
```

So it *looks* like the a solution for this may be to prevent the VS compiler from defining ___local_stdio_printf_options or change the linker setting to accept this style of coding somehow. I don't know why VS would produce code that defines external symbols like this. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: So you're trying to override the MS internal library function `___local_stdio_printf_options`?  Or is that just left-over in MSVC's asm output?  Unlike GCC/clang, I think I've read that MSVC's asm output isn't really intended to be assembled.  In this case that would mean hand-editing to remove functions like this that the library already defines.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah, that definition is left over from MSVC's output. I guess if hand-editing is what I have to do I'll try it. I'm sort of surprised there isn't an easier way to do something like this... I would expect MSVC's compiler to produce assembly and compile that assembly during the normal compilation process?

Comment: No, like most compilers it compiles straight to machine code.  GCC is one of the only widely-used compilers that still always compiles to asm text and feeds that to a separate assembler as part of normal compilation.  MSVC is weird in that it can't produce asm you can use, even if you want it.  If you don't like that, use a better compiler.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the insights!