# Getting LNK errors trying to compile from .asm file using ml.exe

Tags: masm

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("Hello! \n");
    return 0;
}
```

I call first cl /Fa test.c, then call ml test.asm and I get the errors:

> LIBCMT.lib(default_local_stdio_options.obj) : error LNK2005:
> ___local_stdio_printf_options already defined in test.obj
> libvcruntime.lib(undname.obj) : error LNK2005: ___local_stdio_printf_options already defined in test.obj
> test.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

**It works fine if I don't use printf**. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60201854/symbols-already-defined-error-when-compiling-assembly-output-from-visual-studio Peter Cordes says MSVC doesn't produce asm you can use, is that the issue? Seems a bit odd it works without the call to printf?

Comment: Oh am I supposed to be using ml test.obj? That seems to be working after using cl /Fa /c test.c. Sorry I really have no idea what I'm doing and there seems to be no documentation.